# Resource configuration class could not be loaded when trying to open index.html in eclipse

Tags: java, servlets, web-deployment

I am trying to open index.html from eclipse. But I got this error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource configuration class
>   com.sensorhound.things.rest.ThingsApplication could not be loaded.

I am using java EE framework.

Previously, I am writing my front-end code using a Node.js fake server. Then I create a maven project in eclipse to write my back-end code. And I didn't move my front-end code to this project until I finish writing up the back-end code.

What I did to test my front-end code before was start up my wildfly server and Cassandra database, then I will do a mvn wildfly:deploy under my back-end project directory. Then I will go to the front-end code folder and open the index.html in browser. It works fine.

Now I need to wrap up my project so I copy my front-end code to

*src/main/webapps*

directory, and update my project.

But when I try to open the index.html from eclipse. It give me this error.

For more reference, here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>
                com.sensorhound.aigateway.ws.filters.CORSFilter
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletContainer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sensorhound.things.rest.ThingsApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletContainer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sensorhound</groupId>
    <artifactId>aigateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>AI Gateway Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jetty.version>9.3.12.v20160915</jetty.version>
        <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
        <ogm.version>5.0.4.Final</ogm.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.4.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.4.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-cassandra</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
           <version>1.6.1</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- hibernate ogm -->
        <!-- Hibernate OGM Infinispan module; pulls in the OGM core module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- standard APIs dependencies - provided in a Java EE container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add the Narayana Transactions Manager
         an implementation would be provided in a Java EE container,
         but this works nicely in Java SE as well -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.jta</groupId>
            <artifactId>narayana-jta</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossjta</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId> 
            <version>${jetty.version}</version> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource.leveldbjni</groupId>
            <artifactId>leveldbjni-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>aigateway</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                <force>true</force>
<!--                <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname> -->
<!--                <username>${wildfly-user}</username> -->
<!--                <password>${wildfly-password}</password> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you need more information, I am willing to share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by remove servlet related tags in web.xml. Those are the code my co-workers added when using jetty server.